# Janus loading plugins all splits and tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, vim-plugin

I'm using Janus to manage my vim plugins. What I realized is that all plugins are just loaded in one split. If I open more splits or tabs. The plugins are not being loaded. I.E The Rails commands are just available in the vim split where I firstly opened the Nerdtree. If I switch to another split (ctrl+w) or tab, then the rails commands (and maybe other plugins as well) aren't available. if I run the rails command in the nerdtree split, then I cannot use the nerdtree on this split anymore. There is any tweak that I can do to load the rails.vim in all splits and tabs as well?

EDIT: the Janus .vimrc doesn't help too much. but here it is any way

> "" "" Janus setup ""
>
> " Define paths let g:janus_path =
>   escape(fnamemodify(resolve(expand(":p")), ":h"), ' ') let
>   g:janus_vim_path = escape(fnamemodify(resolve(expand(":p" .
>   "vim")), ":h"), ' ') let g:janus_custom_path = expand("~/.janus")
>
> " Source janus's core exe 'source ' . g:janus_vim_path .
>   '/core/before/plugin/janus.vim'
>
> " You should note that groups will be processed by Pathogen in reverse
>   " order they were added. call janus#add_group("tools") call
>   janus#add_group("langs") call janus#add_group("colors")
>
> "" "" Customisations ""
>
> filetype plugin on
>
> if filereadable(expand("~/.vimrc.before"))   source ~/.vimrc.before
>   endif
>
> " Disable plugins prior to loading pathogen exe 'source ' .
>   g:janus_vim_path . '/core/plugins.vim'
>
> "" "" Pathogen setup ""
>
> " Load all groups, custom dir, and janus core call
>   janus#load_pathogen()
>
> " .vimrc.after is loaded after the plugins have loaded

Comment: What is the output of `:pwd` in the NERDTree window *and* in the other window. Is it the same? Does it represent a Rails project? Also, looking at your vimrc may be useful, please append its content to the body of your question.

Comment: they are the same and they do represent a rails project.

Comment: You should drop that janus crap and try with a real normal configuration and see if the problem is still there. Maybe it will be easier to debug, then.

Comment: yes right. But actually the Janus isn't the problem. its just a structured way to organize the vim config/plugins. it doesn't do any ninja voodoo. but thanks.

Comment: The simple fact that Janus hides so many settings in so many files in so many places makes it hard to debug. `~/.vimrc` is where *you* put *your* settings and it's the first thing to look at when there's something going wrong. That janus pseudo-vimrc says nothing and you'd have to post the content of `n` files for us to have a clear picture of your settings. Even then, their execution order would probably not be clear enough… Plus, it's always a good thing to try to reduce the number of things involved to the minimum possible. You could have 70 plugins conflicting with each other.

Comment: i removed and i'm using Vundler now. its fixed.